# xcode storyboard Container View - How do I access the viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, container-view

I'm trying to use storyboard and get things working properly. I've added a a Container View to one of my existing views. When I try to add a reference to this in my view controller `.h` file (ctrl-drag), I get a `IBOutlet UIView *containerView`. How do I get a reference to the container view's view controller instead?  I need the container view controller so I can set it's delegate to my view's controller so they can "talk" to each other.

I have my story board setup as:

[image]

And its referenced in my .h file as:

[image]

Notice in the .h that is is a UIView, not my InstallViewController for the view. How do I add a reference to the view controller? I need to be able to set its delegate.

Comment: Here's the final, ultimate, last-word, maintained, tutorial on that!  https://stackoverflow.com/a/23403979/294884  There are some subtleties you need to know about, they are all explained there in detail and clearly.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

There is another solution by specifying an identifier for the embed segue(s) and retrieve the corresponding view controllers in method `prepareForSegue:`

The advantage of this way is that you needn't rely on a specific order in which your child view controllers are added due to the fact that each child view controller is embedded via an unique segue identifier.

Update 2013-01-17 - Example

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue*)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // -- Master View Controller
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:c_SegueIdEmbedMasterVC])
    {
        self.masterViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        // ...
    }
    // -- Detail View Controller
    else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:c_SegueIdEmbedDetailVC])
    {
        self.detailViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        // ...
    }
}
```

`c_SegueIdEmbedMasterVC` & `c_SegueIdEmbedDetailVC` are constants with the corresponding ID of the segue IDs defined in the storyboard.

Comment: Sorry for the late update. I'm sure you managed the problem by yourself in the meantime but eventually the example code helps other ones in the future.

Comment: God answer. I Tried that trick before, and only after reading this answer I realized that it only works if you setup Segue Identifiers. However I would use isKindOfClass: instead.

Comment: Why are there two view controllers (detail and master)? Isn't it just the one view controller in the container? What other segue are you referring to?

Comment: @shim: In my example project I had a kind of split view with a master and a detail view controller hosted in 2 separate container views - therefore the two view controllers.

Comment: Its a shame that this is the best way of getting a reference to the child view controller.  The whole point of the storyboards is to reduce boilerplate code like this.  I could add the child view controller in `viewDidLoad` in fewer lines of code and it would be more maintainable than this.  Anyone know if this fixed in XCode 6?

Answer (score 14):

When you add a container view the xcode calls the UIViewController method `addChildViewController:`

In your case, you can get the container ViewController looking for it on the SplashViewController's list of `childViewControllers`, something like this:

```
for (UIViewController *childViewController in [self childViewControllers])
{
    if ([childViewController isKindOfClass:[InstallViewController class]])
    {
        //found container view controller
        InstallViewController *installViewController = (InstallViewController *)childViewController;

        //do something with your container view viewcontroller

        break;
    }
}
```

I had the same doubt yesterday :)

Comment: I am trying to do something similar and what i don't get is the "vc" in InstallViewController *installViewController = (InstallViewController *)vc;

Comment: You are right, it should've been "childViewController". I've just fixed in the post. Sorry for taking that much to reply.

Comment: This approach feels a bit like a "workaround" to me. Doesn't it?

Comment: Well, it did the trick :) Does the prepareForSegue method is called when a Container View is added to another view?

Answer (score 2):

The answer of [Vitor Franchi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/973801/vitor-franchi) is correct but could be more performant and convenient. Especially when accessing the child view controller several times.

Create a readonly property

```
@interface MyViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, weak, readonly) InstallViewController *cachedInstallViewController;
@end
```

Then create a convenient getter method

```
- (InstallViewController *)installViewController
{
    if (_cachedInstallViewController) return _cachedInstallViewController;

    __block InstallViewController *blockInstallViewController = nil;
    NSArray *childViewControllers = self.childViewControllers;
    [childViewControllers enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id childViewController, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

        if ([childViewController isMemberOfClass:InstallViewController.class])
        {
            blockInstallViewController = childViewController;
            *stop = YES;
        }
    }];

    _cachedInstallViewController = blockInstallViewController;

    return _cachedInstallViewController;
}
```

From now on access the child view controller that way

```
[self.installViewController doSomething];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UIView* viewInsideOfContainer = installerView.subviews[0];
```

Will give you the UIView inside of the UIViewController that your controller UIView references. You can cast the subview to any type that inherits from UIView.

Comment: I'm not sure I like making that assumption, but it's useful to know.

Comment: That's not the universal way: view hierarchy can change and this method won't work.

Answer (score 0):

If the nib is loaded it will call addChildViewController as part of the initialisation process

so a performant solution could be also to overwrite

```
- (void)addChildViewController:(UIViewController *)childController
```

there you can catch your childController e.g. by comparing its Class  and assign it to a property / ivar

```
-(void)addChildViewController:(UIViewController *)childController
{
    [super addChildViewController:childController];

    if([childController isKindOfClass:[InstallViewController class]])
    {
        self.installViewController = (InstallViewController *)childController;
    }
```

}

This will save your from iterating trough the childViewControllers.